# Wiring home network patch panel (568A vs 568B)

Tags: wiring, low-voltage, patch

I've bought a data patch panel in order to cleanup my home network wiring (which was a mess). Before wiring the patch panel I didn't read about the two wiring options: 568A and 568B.

I've wired the patch panel as indicated (panel is 568A). I've installed one cat5e outlet in order to test if it was working properly.

I've used a basic network cable tester to see if everything was ok and it wasn't successful.

After reading more on the subject, I realized that my patch panel is wired 568A and the outlet is wired 568B.  So my two options would be to 
1. Re-wire the outlet to 568A; or
2. Re-wire the patch panel to 568B

What is the best option ? Is there another option ?

[image: Patch Panel]

[image: Outlet]

Comment: Not related to the question asked, but don't forget to trim the "pigtails" you have sticking off of the terminations on both the panel and the jack. They can degrade your signal.

Comment: You also have the pairs untwisted a bit more than you should on that connection. Each pair should remain twisted right up until it hits the connector block.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Agree, though Cat5e is a lot more forgiving in that regard than Cat6 is

Comment: The B variant is more common

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry if this simple answer comes across as too basic. But you really could get the decided by looking at your own setup.

1. Rewire at the end that has more slack cable in case you need to cut it off some to re-do it.
2. Evaluate if the wall jack is reliable if re-wired. It may need replacing if not reliable for multiple re-configurations.
3. Evaluate if the press fit connections on the patch block are designed for multi termination usage.
4. Work at the end that is physically easier to access.